# Trying to understand the motion of a high speed particle?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, velocity

To start we have a single proton. We place are proton in a circular particle accelerator, and bring the proton up to speed of 0.99C. we then accelerate the entire particle accelerator on the horizontal plane up to 0.1C.
What does the movement of the proton look like from a top down observer?

Comment: For an observer sitting on top of the accelerator, the motion looks like a circle. For an observer moving relative to the accelerator one would apply the appropriate transformation.

Comment: What did you try to answer this question yourself?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a conceptual question and not a "do my homework" question.

Comment: Agreed, it seems a perfectly good question to me.